# Why doesn't pickling something in python save the exact thing I save?

Tags: python, save, pickle

I have a problem that when I pickle something it doesn't save the exact text to what I saved. The thing I wanted to save was a list, but in the code it adds stuff to the list (I don't know if that's what affects it).

```
import pickle

inventoryFile = 'inventory.file'

with open(inventoryFile, "wb") as fi:
    pickle.dump(inventory, fi)

with open(inventoryFile, "rb") as fi:
    inventory = pickle.load(fi)
```

`inventory` was a list that I kept adding to. When I looked into the `inventory.file` file, all it said was

```
�]q�.
```

I don't know what it means.  Also I'm a beginner at Python, so I'm not too good.

Comment: what do you  mean when you looked into the inventory.file? you mean when  you viewed it in the file system outside of python?

Comment: The only thing you need to worry about is whether the `inventory` object returned from `.load()` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pickling something doesn't create a plain-text representation of an object; it creates a file that can be opened to produce the same object in Python.  This representation isn't designed to be human-readable (hence the need to "unpickle" it with `pickle.load()`.  So you can't open the pickled file with a text editor and expect to see the list.

If `pickle.load(fi)` is producing the same list that you saved, then the pickling is going fine.  If you want to create a human-readable file instead, try:

- converting the list to a string (for example `', '.join(seq)`) and saving that
- another module for data storage (like [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

pickling will save a representation of the object into the file. that wont be a human readable representation it will be one that can be reloaded into memory by unpickling it again. we can see this if after pickling the `inventory` we set it to `None` then we load it via pickle from the file you see we get the exact same representation of the list back.

```py
import pickle

inventoryFile = 'inventory.file'
inventory = [1,2,3]
print(inventory)
with open(inventoryFile, "wb") as fi:
    pickle.dump(inventory, fi)

inventory = None
print(inventory)

with open(inventoryFile, "rb") as fi:
        inventory = pickle.load(fi)
print(inventory)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3]
None
[1, 2, 3]
```

If we look in the file from just a plain text editor we see

```
�]q (KKKe.
```

but this is not designed to be human readable.